# Creating my own iTunes Artwork

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How do I create iTunes Artwork for my app?
Currently, I have the default file, an image of the cocos2D logo, but how could I possibly edit this? 
The file type is apparently an Unix Executable.
 Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`iTunesArtwork` is just a PNG image without the ".png" extension. Use any editor that supports PNG, and lop off the filename extension when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Take a png image of 512*512 and named it iTunesArtwork and remove.png extension.
That's it.